# Derivative of dot product confusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inner-products

I know this may be trivial but I don't know how to word the question to find a proper explanation online.

> Given $\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R^n}$, what would be the derivative of $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}$?

My intuition from dealing with derivatives with scalars tells me that we treat $\mathbf{y}$ as a constant, and the derivative of $f$ would simply be $\mathbf{y}$. However, I am wondering if my thought process is correct; in another word, would the same method dealing with scalars apply to dot product?

Comment: yeah, you can justify it by expanding

Comment: The preferred symbol for the dot product is $\cdot$ (`\cdot`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes!

1. If $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}\bullet \mathbf{y}$, then $f^\prime(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{y}$.
2. To see this, first use the definition of derivative:
   $$f^\prime(\mathbf{x}) = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} f(\mathbf{x})\right]_k$$

   (The total derivative can be defined as a vector of partial derivatives.)
3. Then look at a specific component $k$ of the derivative and expand the definition of dot product:
   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \mathbf{x}\bullet \mathbf{y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \sum_i x_iy_i   $$
4. Now, only one of those terms in the sum depends on $x_k$. It is the term $x_ky_k$ (which occurs when $i=k$), and its derivative with respect to $x_k$ is just $y_k$.
5. Hence the total derivative $f^\prime(\mathbf{x})$ is the vector $[y_k]_k$, or in other words $[y_1, y_2, \ldots] = \mathbf{y}$, as required.

And in general, the rules of calculus (such as the product rule) tend to generalize to matrix equations.

Comment: Technically, the correct answer is $\mathbf y^\top$, since we have a linear map, not a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Technical clarification: the [Fréchet derivative/differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) of a function $f$ in a point is a linear function: the *best* (if exists) linear approximation of $f$ near of the point. If $f$ is linear (your case), the best linear approximation near of the point is the *same* $f$:
$$Df(x_0) = f.$$
Is your $f$ the same "thing" that $\mathbf y$? Well, both "things" (linear function, point) have the *same* coordinates in the (wrongly called) canonical basis of their spaces.